# flutter how to terminate all ongoing actions when the back button is pressed?

Tags: flutter

I want to terminate any currently executing function task when the back button is clicked.How can I do it?(I want to terminate the below function if I press back button)

```
 void getData(String locale, String searchKey, List<String> contentType,
      int categoryID, int start, int limit) async {
    print('get data');
    temp = (await context.read(knowledgeBaseViewModelProvider).getCategoryData(
        locale, searchKey, contentType, categoryID, start, limit))!;
    _isLoding = false;
    if(mounted){
      setState(() {
        if (temp.length == 0 ) {
          isEnd = true;
          momAlertBox(
            context,
            "Alert",
            "No More Data.Try Another Category!",
            "Oky.",
                () => Navigator.pop(context, 'OK'),
          );
        } else {
          isEnd = false;
        }
        isLodingState = false;
        items.addAll(temp);
      });
    }
  }
```

The back button

```
BackButton(
 onPress: () => {
 Navigator.pop(context)},
 svgAssetsPath: "assets/icons/icon_back.svg",
 height: SizeConfig.devicePixelRatio * 8,
 width: SizeConfig.devicePixelRatio * 8,
 ),
```